# Is there a name for a formula to calculate ascending numbers to a quadratic-like sequence?

Tags: quadratic-forms, computer-science

For e.g. any range of number 0 - n

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6

to:

> 0 2 4 6 4 2 0

Is there a name for this kind of formula or calculation?

Comment: Would you clarify the mapping?

Comment: Sorry Charles, I do not know the mapping too, that's what I want to find out as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [tent map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tent_map). In your case it'd be scaled to $f(x) = 2 \min(x, 6-x)$.